# Issue with removing jquery class

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

Could anyone help me out with this?
Basically I want the script to add 'active' class to 'li' on click, and remove it on another click - well, it adds the class and automatically deletes it :-) I would really appreciate any solution.

PS. I have looked around other questions concerning this issue, but I haven't found any answer that would help me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('li').each(function() {
        var faq = jQuery(this), state = true, answer = faq.next('.answer').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
        faq.click(function() {
            state = !state;
            answer.slideToggle(state);
            faq.addClass('active',state);
              if(jQuery("li").hasClass("active")) {
              jQuery(".active").remove(); }
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMuRs/)

```
jQuery(".active").removeClass(); }
```

fixes half of the issue

Comment: `.addClass` does not accept a second parameter.. you must be thinking about `.toggleClass`

Comment: Doesn't help...http://jsfiddle.net/tc6Cj/1/

Comment: @AndyAndy: check my update and in the answer..!! thats what i understood..!! tell me if you still is not satisfied with it..!! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

it is actually [**.removeClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) that you have to try..!!

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tc6Cj/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('li').each(function() {
        var faq = jQuery(this), state = true, answer = faq.next('.answer').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
        faq.click(function() {
            state = !state;
            answer.slideToggle(state);
            faq.addClass('active',state);
              if(jQuery("li").hasClass("active")) {
              jQuery(".active").removeClass(); }
        });
    });
});
```

**OR**

using [**.toggleClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('li').each(function() {
        var faq = jQuery(this), state = true, answer = faq.next('.answer').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
        faq.click(function() {
            state = !state;
            answer.slideToggle(state);
            faq.addClass('active',state);
           $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp3S3/)

**Update**

updated based on @AndyAndy 's comment :

> imagine that
>
> has a "+" icon, and on click it changes to "-" icon
>   and answer shows up.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('li').each(function() {
        var faq = jQuery(this), answer = faq.next('.answer').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
        faq.click(function() {

            answer.slideToggle('.active');


            if($(this).text()=='+')
            {
            $(this).text('-');
            }
            else{
            $(this).text('+');
            }


        });
    });
});
```

[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8r8Zc/)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I have been missing!

Comment: Actually when I look into the code it does not add the class...any idea?

Comment: @AndyAndy you are adding it faq.addClass('active',state);

Comment: @AndyAndy: if you need that way try using jQuery(".active").toggleClass();

Comment: It only adds empty "class" attribute so the final outcome is  <li class>Question1</li> instead of <li class="active">Question1</li>..

Comment: @AndyAndy: what actually you need ?? you need the answers to show up on cliking the question and hide the answer on the second click ,right ??

Comment: yes, show/hide answer on click and add "active" class to the <li> element at the same time. I appreciate your help

Comment: @AndyAndy: what actually in the output you require by adding the active class..!! do you need  only one answer to be shown at a time?

Comment: No, multiple answers. I need the "active" class to change the <span> attribute value on click. I.e. imagine that <li> has a "+" icon, and on click it changes to "-" icon and answer shows up.

Comment: @AndyAndy: actually i can't get you, but for your final answer you only need the js in this http://jsfiddle.net/RX9CF/

Comment: @AndyAndy, you should post your HTML if since it is not clear from the question what you are trying to achieve..